# Java: Selenium returns script timeout instead of element not found

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've got a strange problem. This happens with a page and a PageObject that exists amidst other pages and PageObjects where Selenium works as expected. But for this page (and PageObject), Selenium does not.

When I try to access a page element that is not on the page, instead of return "element not found", selenium times out after a couple of minutes with the following errors:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
...
org.openqa.selenium.ScriptTimeoutException: script timeout
(Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.105)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'ubuntu', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: 
'5.3.0-7648-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_265'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 84.0.4147.105, c
chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 84.0.4147.105 (a6b12dfad666..., userDataDir: 
/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:36301}, 
javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, 
platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, 
timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and 
notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: a87f945bc7eb66a98cec5f0b2416b47a
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeAsyncScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:506)
at 
no.husbanken.e2e.rammeverk.selenium.driver.ExtendedWebDriver.isPageReady(ExtendedWebDriver.java:46)
 at 
no.husbanken.e2e.rammeverk.selenium.driver.ExtendedWebDriver.findElement(ExtendedWebDriver.java:65)
```

I know that a timeout is not very strange in itself, but when I try to access non-existing elements on other pages, they return the expected "element not found".

The PageObject:

```
public class VedleggPage2 {
    private ExtendedWebDriver driver;
    private String url;

    @FindBy(css = "[data-e2e-selector=sidetittel]")
    private WebElement sidetittel;
    @FindBy(css = "[data-e2e-selector=vedleggtekst]")
    private WebElement vedleggtekst;

    public VedleggPage2() {
        this.driver = Browser.extendedDriver();
        this.url = ConfigManager.config.getEsoknadWebUrl() + "soknad/";
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void navigerTil() {
        navigerTil(Session.scenarioState.getSoknadId(SOKNAD_1_TAG));

        //For testing purposes:
        List<WebElement> jajaja = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("sidetittel"));
        Boolean janei = sidetittel.isDisplayed();
        Boolean neija = vedleggtekst.isDisplayed();
        sidetittel.click();
        String s = sidetittel.getText()
        driver.findElement(By.id("sidetittel")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-e2e-selector=sidetittel]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-e2e-selector=vedleggtekst]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("notexisting")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("notexisting")).getText();
        Boolean visible1 = driver.findElement(By.id("sidetittel")).isDisplayed();
        Boolean visible2 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-e2e-
          selector=vedleggtekst]")).isDisplayed();
        Boolean visible3 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-e2e-
          selector=vedleggtekst]")).isDisplayed();
        Boolean visible4 = driver.findElement(By.id("notexisting")).isDisplayed();
        
    }
}
```

All of the attempts to access existing and non-existing elements under the "//For testing purposes" line results in the long timeout and script timeout error above, instead of "element not found". Also, some of the elements are definitely there, and should not result in any error. There's nothing in the (very basic) PageObject code that should result in this behavior.

I've even tried placing the problem lines in other PageObjects, and they behave exactly the same there. When those other PageObjects are used to access their respective pages, they work as expected. So right now it seems that this happens for this specific webpage.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: More troubleshooting revealed that if I navigate to another page in the same site/app, it works like a charm. So the problem with the timeout is with the specific page (and others, since I doubt only ONE page is like this).

UPDATE2: The driver initialization and isPageReady() method(s) are in a framework separated from the application code. Here's the relevant code, I think:

ExtendedWebDriver.java:

```
public ExtendedWebDriver(final WebDriver webDriver, final String 
venteScript) {
    if (!(webDriver instanceof JavascriptExecutor)) {
        throw new WebDriverException("The WebDriver instance must implement 
        JavaScriptExecutor interface.");
    }
    if (venteScript == null || venteScript.isEmpty()) {
        throw new WebDriverException("Ingen ventescript spesifisert");
    }
    this.webDriver = webDriver;
    this.jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
    this.venteScript = venteScript;
}

public JavascriptExecutor getJsExecutor() {
    return jsExecutor;
}

public void isPageReady() {
    Object response = jsExecutor.executeAsyncScript(venteScript);
    if (response != null) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        response = jsExecutor.executeAsyncScript(venteScript);
        if(response!=null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(format("Responsen fra 
             isPageReady() skal alltid være null, men var: %s", response));
        }
    }
}
```

WebDriverFactory.java:

```
public class WebDriverFactory {

    public static ExtendedWebDriver getExtendedWebDriver(WebDriver driver, 
      SeleniumOptions.WebAppTeknologi teknologi) {
        return new ExtendedWebDriver(driver, JsUtils.getScript(teknologi));
    }
}
```

JsUtils.java:

```
public class JsUtils {
    private static final HashMap<SeleniumOptions.WebAppTeknologi, String> scripts;

    static {
        scripts = new HashMap<>();
        initScripts();
    }

    private static void initScripts() {
        scripts.put(SeleniumOptions.WebAppTeknologi.ANGULAR, getAngularScript());
        scripts.put(SeleniumOptions.WebAppTeknologi.PRIMEFACES, getPrimefacesScript());
    }

    private static String getAngularScript() {
        return "function getNg1Hooks(t,e){function n(t){try{if(!e&&angular.getTestability){var n=angular.getTestability(t);if" +
            "(n)return{$$testability:n}}else{var i=angular.element(t).injector();if(i)return{$injector:i}}}catch(t)" +
            "{}}function i(t){for(var e=document.querySelectorAll(t),i=0;i<e.length;i++){var r=n(e[i]);if(r)return r}}if(t)" +
            "return i(t);if(window.__TESTABILITY__NG1_APP_ROOT_INJECTOR__){var r=window" +
            ".__TESTABILITY__NG1_APP_ROOT_INJECTOR__,a=null;try{a=r.get(\"$$testability\")}catch(t){}return{$injector:r," +
            "$$testability:a}}return n(document.body)||i(\"[ng-app]\")||i(\"[ng\\\\:app]\")||i(\"[ng-controller]\")||i" +
            "(\"[ng\\\\:controller]\")}waitForAngular=function(t,e){try{var n=e;if(!window.angular&&!window" +
            ".getAngularTestability)throw new Error(\"both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  " +
            "This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, " +
            "which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details\");!function(e){if" +
            "(window.angular){var n=getNg1Hooks(t);if(n)if(n.$$testability)n.$$testability.whenStable(e);else{if(!n" +
            ".$injector)throw t?new Error(\"root element (\"+t+\") has no injector. this may mean it is not inside ng-app" +
            ".\"):new Error('Could not automatically find injector on page: \"'+window.location.toString()+'\".  Consider " +
            "using config.rootEl');n.$injector.get(\"$browser\").notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(e)}else e()}else e()}" +
            "(function(){if(window.getAngularTestability){if(t){var e=null,i=document.querySelector(t);try{e=window" +
            ".getAngularTestability(i)}catch(t){}if(e)return void e.whenStable(n)}var r=window.getAllAngularTestabilities()" +
            ",a=r.length;if(0===a)return void n();var o=function(){0==--a&&n()};r.forEach(function(t){t.whenStable(o)})" +
            "}else n()})}catch(t){e(t.message)}},waitForAngular(\"body\",arguments[arguments.length-1]);";
    }

    private static String getPrimefacesScript() {
        return "waitForPrimefaces=function(e){try{if(!window.jQuery)throw window.jQuery?new Error(\"Unknown Error\"):new Error" +
            "(\"window.jQuery is undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-jquery page or because your test " +
            "involves client-side navigation\");if(WaitForAjax(),void 0===window.PrimeFaces)throw new Error(\"typeof " +
            "PrimeFaces  is undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-primefaces page or because your test " +
            "involves client-side navigation\");WaitForPF(),e(null)}catch(i){e(i.message)}};var WaitForAjax=function()" +
            "{0!==window.jQuery.active&&setTimeout(WaitForAjax,50)},WaitForPF=function(){window.PrimeFaces.ajax.Queue" +
            ".isEmpty()||setTimeout(WaitForPF,50)};waitForPrimefaces(arguments[arguments.length-1]);";
    }

    public static String getScript(SeleniumOptions.WebAppTeknologi key) {
        return scripts.get(key);
    }
```

Comment: include your driver initialization... (ExtendedWebDriver)  It looks like something is trying to detect whether the page is ready and is timing out.  You really don't need that... using expected conditions with webdriverwaits would be better.

Comment: See my update. If I navigate to another page (previous page in the application), there are no problems. So the timeout seems to happen at that specific page. Since the driver initialization is the same (done in the Selenium framework), that shouldn't be affect just the one page, should it?

Comment: it could it's hard to say without seeing what is done to detect page ready state... my guess is you're executing a script to find that... it will also depend on whether a get was used in the previous step.  Selenium will automatically wait for a page ready state after a get or navigating to a different page (it does not wait for a javascript DOM update...)  Some sites will "lazy load" elements after page ready state, so that might be the purpose of it.  Again, better to use expected conditions and webdriverwaits for that kind of thing.  The reason is async nature of JS calls/timing conflict.

Comment: So the page could be ready... then a script on the site fires to lazy load some more stuff into the DOM... then you execute a script... when your script executes is uncertain... is it before the lazy loading script or after?  You won't really know for sure.  Some scripts also constantly poll in a way where page will never return a ready state.  (I think that's somewhat rare, though...)

Comment: I've added the code from the ExtendedWebdriver class in the Framework. Do you see anything there that could be a culprit?

Comment: yes.  You are using javascript to see if the page is ready.  Best to use webdriver waits with expected conditions.

Comment: Ah. Pardon my noobness, but the framework code is not mine. It's in the isPageReady() method, right? I should probably rewrite that then. But there's probably a reason why Javascript is used in the first place. Could it have something to do with the fact that the application is written first in AngularJS, then later upgraded to Angular8?

Comment: hard to say without seeing the site... but it might be their way to deal with lazy loading part of a page.  (Where you'd see placeholders after a page ready state, and then another script fires to populate.)  This can be problematic depending on the markup, but you should be able to use webdriver waits and expected conditions to detect those elements.

Comment: a tipoff is when someone uses a sleep: "Thread.sleep(1000);"  is in your ispageready method.  It's a hack and assumes that this amount of time will always be enough.  WebDriverWaits are designed to deal with JS DOM updates and are the better way to go.  They will only wait the amount of time needed for the expected condition to be met, or timeout after an amount of time that you set.  PageReady states during javascript execution also have a number of different in between states depending on browser:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState